# Get value from EntityType Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, frameworks

I can not get value from EntityType. I have last version 3.3.6.

```
class BuildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
       $options)
    {
    $builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
    ->add('team', CollectionType::class, array(
        // each entry in the array will be an "email" field
        'entry_type' => TeamType::class,
        // these options are passed to each "email" type
        'entry_options'  => array(
            'attr'      => array('class' => 'form-control'),
        ),
        'label' => false,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'mapped' => false
    ));
 }
}
```

---

```
class TeamType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
      $options)
    {

    $builder
    ->add('name', EntityType::class, array(
        'placeholder' => 'Choice a champ',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Champions',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'dropdown'),
    ));
}
```

I tried all but i cannot take value of 'name' of TeamType. After submission form, i do

```
foreach ($form["team"]->getData() as $value) {
   'name' => $value['name']
```

but the value is empty. If i try dump request and the value is there. The other values i can get it and save in Database. Only EntityType i can not. 
Someone know how do?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the `$form['team']`? Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: Curious, if `TeamType` does contain only one field, why did you extract it into separate form type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityType returns as the object. You should use model getter functions.

```
$form->get('name')->getData()->getId(); // getName() vs..
```

Here is a similar example.

[symfony how get selected data from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016260/symfony-how-get-selected-data-from-select/46017250#46017250)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using `ManyToOne` relationship.

**With AJAX**

if you are trying get data after submitted, You can do this first in your view:

```
   $('#elementWhereYouAreTEAMType').find('input').each(function (i,v) {
       var valTeam = $(this).val(); //take value

       // adding data, create an associative array.
       formData.append("team["+ i +"]", valTeam);

   });
```

You must put `formData` like `data` argument to ajax JQuery
Now, server side:

```
public function createTeamNow(Request $request) {// ajax

  $teams = $request->request->get('team'); // getting array

  if(!is_null($teams)) {// if user added team
    foreach ($teams as $team) {
       // dump($team);

       //create an instance for each element, it does not replace a data with the above
       $teamType = new TeamType(); 
       $teamName->setName($team);
       $this->em->persist($teamType);
    }
  }

}
```

**Without AJAX**

```
/**
 * @Route("/slim/1" , name="data_x")
 */ 
public function slimExampleAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(TeamType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() /*&& $form->isValid()*/) {
        // When you've ManyToOne relationship, that field returns ArrayCollection class, it has several method to get data on differents ways, iterate with it, for example toArray is one
        $data = $form->getData();
        dump($data->getDescription()->toArray());die;
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:view.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```